# How to select a cell in datagrid onClick in ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I am importing a column in datatable to my grid. Now I want navigate to a new page on selecting a cell in grid by fetching the selected value. I have tried this by including bound field in my grid like

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GDV_1" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GDV_1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateSelectButton="false" DataKeyNames="SROID">
      <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="SRONameinEnglish" HtmlEncode="False" DataFormatString="<a target='_blank' href='Test.aspx?code={0}>ClickHere</a>" />
      </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Doing this way my requirement is achieved but the all cells are displaying Common text `Click here` instead of showing data from Database.

Please give your suggestion on how to get the value from database into cell and make it `clickable`. I don't want to use `Select button`. Please find my current output.
This is my current output I want my data from `DB` instead of `ClickHere`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use TemplateField

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnk<%# Eval("SRONameinEnglish")%>"><%# Eval("SRONameinEnglish")%></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

and click of LinkButton put your code to navigate anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you are binding `boundfield` with static `a tag` which have `href` attribute so your not able to change text on that `boundfield` from your database.To get your approach you should 
use `TemplateField` and bind data with text attribute using `eval keyword` as below example.

Try it:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**OR**

you can also bind link with your hyperlink using `NavigateUrl` property of hyperlink as below example.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:HyperLink id="HyperLink2" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("YourUrl") %>' Text='<%#Eval("name") %>' runat="server"/>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I hope it will helpful to you.